# Cakephp : 3 Pagination design has broken After Add Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I have added this code in my index.ctp file, Here design has been broken when I am trying to add next and previous option.

```
<div class="paginator">
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
        <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?></p>
</div>
```

Image looking like

[image]

Here for

```
<?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
```

It have created an ul with class pagination, So I need to add prev and next list into this ul list, How can I do that? May any body help me please.

Comment: Seems like the previous and next are not `li` items therefore they're going outside the ul.. Is that the case when you inspect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the discussion in this [Pull Request](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui/pull/61)

the solution is this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
    <?= $this->Paginator->numbers(['before' => '', 'after' => '']) ?>
    <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: May you provide me the link ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working fine for me.

```
<div class="pagination pagination-right">
<span class="pull-left">
    <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->counter(
            'Showing {{start}} to {{end}} of total {{count}}'
    );
    ?>
</span>
<ul class="">
    <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev(__('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next'), array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by below code, here is the link [solution](https://github.com/ayman-alkom/bootstrap-ui/commit/b67ad111c6e176b4d06996f12c8a6ab099c11103).@ Ayman Alkum has given the clue.

```
 <ul class="pagination">
          <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
          <?= $this->Paginator->numbers(['before' => '', 'after' => '']) ?>
          <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
 </ul>
```